# Can't get Association table to eager load with Movie for particlular User, to show if the User who added the movie is being followed or not Flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

```
class Movie(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['genre']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    username = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.String(100))


class User(db.Model,UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    movies = db.relationship('Movie', backref='author', lazy='joined')
    followed = db.relationship('User', secondary=followers,
    primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id==id),
    secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id==id),
    backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='joined'), lazy='joined')

followers = db.Table('followers', 
db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key = True),
db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key = True) )

def get_all_movies_follow():
    
    qry = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.id.desc()).all()

    movies_schema = MovieSchema(many=True)

    return movies_schema.dump(qry)
```

How to get back an collection (array) where I have a property that shows whether
When I eager_load followers table it's still won't show up in the query.
``` #movi = Movie.query.outerjoin(followers, followers.c.followed_id == Movie.user_id).options(contains_eager( Movie.us).contains_eager( 'followers')).order_by(Movie.id.desc()).all()

````
Also when I try to use follow unfollow function I get Select statement 'SELECT *
FROM followers, movie AS movie_1
WHERE followers.followed_id = movie_1.user_id' returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation; specify correlate(<tables>) to control correlation manually.

which in short is def unfollow(id):
...         
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    db.session.commit()

def follow(self, user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.append(user)
    def unfollow(self, user):
        if self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.remove(user)

    def is_following(self, user):
        return self.query.filter(followers.c.followed_id==user.id).count()>0


So I tried adding this to Movie class:  ```following = column_property( exists().where(followers.c.followed_id==user_id)) but it has to be also restricted on current_user.id=followers.c.follower_id
````

I am thinking maybe statement that will be included when I query for the Movie

Answer (score 0):

ok, so this works, granted that I included following in the schema to dump on MovieSchema.
But it has a problem. If there are no matches to (followers.c.follower_id) so user is not following anyone. then I get an empty result and no movie gets loaded at all.

```
class Movie(db.Model)
...
following = column_property( exists().where(followers.c.followed_id==user_id).correlate_except(followers))

and in query
qry = db.session.query(Movie).filter(followers.c.follower_id == current_user.id).all()
```